# Swift function object wrapper in apple/swift

Tags: swift

After reading:

- https://github.com/rodionovd/SWRoute/wiki/Function-hooking-in-Swift
- https://github.com/rodionovd/SWRoute/blob/master/SWRoute/rd_get_func_impl.c

I understood that Swift function pointer is wrapped by `swift_func_wrapper` and `swift_func_object` (according to the article in 2014).

I guess this still works in Swift 3, but I couldn't find which file in https://github.com/apple/swift best describes these structs.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Those articles are quite old and seem to refer to Swift 1. As of Swift 2, C function pointers *are* imported to Swift. – Is there a concrete problem that you  are trying to solve?

Comment: @MartinR I'm curious about how functions/closures are structured inside Swift core. For example, `MemoryLayout<(Int) -> Int>.size` will return 16 bytes, not a single  8 byte pointer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I *believe* these details are mainly part of the implementation of [Swift's IRGen](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/lib/IRGen) – I don't think you'll find any friendly structs in the source showing you the full structure of various Swift function values. Therefore if you want to do some digging into this, I would recommend examining the IR emitted by the compiler.

You can do this by running the command:

```
xcrun swiftc -emit-ir main.swift | xcrun swift-demangle > main.irgen
```

which will emit the IR (with demangled symbols) for a -Onone build. You can find [the documentation for LLVM IR here](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html).

The following is some interesting stuff that I've been able to learn from going through the IR myself in a Swift 3.1 build. Note that this is *all* subject to change in future Swift versions (at least until Swift is ABI stable). It goes without saying that the code examples given below are only for demonstration purposes; and shouldn't ever be used in actual production code.

---

### Thick function values

At a very basic level, function values in Swift are simple things – they're defined in the IR as:

```
%swift.function = type { i8*, %swift.refcounted* }
```

which is the raw function pointer `i8*`, along with a pointer to its *context* `%swift.refcounted*`, where `%swift.refcounted` is defined as:

```
%swift.refcounted = type { %swift.type*, i32, i32 }
```

which is the structure of a simple reference-counted object, containing a pointer to the object's metadata, along with two 32 bit values.

These two 32 bit values are used for the reference count of the object. Together , they can either represent (as of Swift 4):

- The strong and unowned reference count of the object + some flags, including whether the object uses native Swift reference counting (as opposed to Obj-C reference counting), and whether the object has a side table.

or

- A pointer to a side table, which contains the above, plus the weak reference count of the object (on forming a weak reference to an object, if it doesn't already have a side table, one will be created).

For further reading on the internals of Swift reference counting, Mike Ash has a [great blog post on the subject](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html).

The context of a function usually adds extra values onto the end of this `%swift.refcounted` structure. These values are dynamic things that the function needs upon being called (such as any values that it has captured, or any parameters that it has been partially applied with). In quite a few cases, function values won't need a context, so the pointer to the context will simply be `nil`.

When the function comes to be called, Swift will simply pass in the context as the last parameter. If the function doesn't have a context parameter, the calling convention appears to allow it to be safely passed anyway.

The storing of the function pointer along with the context pointer is called a *thick* function value,
 and is how Swift usually stores function values of known type (as opposed to a *thin* function value which is just the function pointer).

So, this explains why `MemoryLayout<(Int) -> Int>.size` returns 16 bytes – because it's made up of two pointers (each being a word in length, i.e 8 bytes on a 64 bit platform).

When thick function values are passed into function parameters (where those parameters are of non-generic type), Swift appears to pass the raw function pointer and context as separate parameters.

---

### Capturing values

When a closure captures a value, this value will be put into a heap-allocated box (although the value itself can get stack-promoted in the case of a non-escaping closure – see later section). This box will be available to the function through the context object ([the relevant IR](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/f3e0baf3dd4d20d614629b34936b1977#capturing-values)).

For a closure that just captures a single value, Swift just makes the box *itself* the context of the function (no need for extra indirection). So you'll have a function value which looks like a `ThickFunction<Box<T>>` from the following structures:

```
// The structure of a %swift.function.
struct ThickFunction<Context> {

    // the raw function pointer
    var ptr: UnsafeRawPointer

    // the context of the function value – can be nil to indicate
    // that the function has no context.
    var context: UnsafePointer<Context>?
}

// The structure of a %swift.refcounted.
struct RefCounted {

    // pointer to the metadata of the object
    var type: UnsafeRawPointer

    // the reference counting bits.
    var refCountingA: UInt32
    var refCountingB: UInt32
}

// The structure of a %swift.refcounted, with a value tacked onto the end.
// This is what captured values get wrapped in (on the heap).
struct Box<T> {
    var ref: RefCounted
    var value: T
}
```

In fact, we can actually verify this for ourselves by running the following:

```
// this wrapper is necessary so that the function doesn't get put through a reabstraction
// thunk when getting typed as a generic type T (such as with .initialize(to:))
struct VoidVoidFunction {
    var f: () -> Void
}

func makeClosure() -> () -> Void {
    var i = 5
    return { i += 2 }
}

let f = VoidVoidFunction(f: makeClosure())

let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<VoidVoidFunction>.allocate(capacity: 1)
ptr.initialize(to: f)

let ctx = ptr.withMemoryRebound(to: ThickFunction<Box<Int>>.self, capacity: 1) { 
    $0.pointee.context! // force unwrap as we know the function has a context object.
}

print(ctx.pointee) 
// Box<Int>(ref:
//     RefCounted(type: 0x00000001002b86d0, refCountingA: 2, refCountingB: 2),
//     value: 5
// )

f.f() // call the closure – increment the captured value.

print(ctx.pointee)
// Box<Int>(ref:
//     RefCounted(type: 0x00000001002b86d0, refCountingA: 2, refCountingB: 2),
//     value: 7
// )

ptr.deinitialize()
ptr.deallocate(capacity: 1)
```

We can see that by calling the function between printing out the value of the context object, we can observe the changing in value of the captured variable `i`.

For multiple captured values, we need extra indirection, as the boxes cannot be stored directly as the given function's context, and may be captured by other closures. This is done by adding pointers to the boxes to the end of a `%swift.refcounted`.

For example:

```
struct TwoCaptureContext<T, U> {

    // reference counting header
    var ref: RefCounted

    // pointers to boxes with captured values...
    var first: UnsafePointer<Box<T>>
    var second: UnsafePointer<Box<U>>
}

func makeClosure() -> () -> Void {
    var i = 5
    var j = "foo"
    return { i += 2; j += "b" }
}

let f = VoidVoidFunction(f: makeClosure())

let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<VoidVoidFunction>.allocate(capacity: 1)
ptr.initialize(to: f)

let ctx = ptr.withMemoryRebound(to:
                  ThickFunction<TwoCaptureContext<Int, String>>.self, capacity: 1) {
    $0.pointee.context!.pointee
}

print(ctx.first.pointee.value, ctx.second.pointee.value) // 5 foo

f.f() // call the closure – mutate the captured values.

print(ctx.first.pointee.value, ctx.second.pointee.value) // 7 foob

ptr.deinitialize()
ptr.deallocate(capacity: 1)
```

---

### Passing functions into parameters of generic type

You'll note that in the previous examples, we used a `VoidVoidFunction` wrapper for our function values. This is because otherwise, when being passed into a parameter of generic type (such as `UnsafeMutablePointer`'s `initialize(to:)` method), Swift will put a function value through some reabstraction thunks in order to unify its calling convention to one where the arguments and return are passed by reference, rather than value ([the relevant IR](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/f3e0baf3dd4d20d614629b34936b1977#generic-reabstraction-thunks)).

But now our function value has a pointer to the thunk, rather than the actual function we want to call. So how does the thunk know which function to call? The answer is simple – Swift puts the function that we want to the thunk to call in the *context* itself, which will therefore look like this:

```
// the context object for a reabstraction thunk – contains an actual function to call.
struct ReabstractionThunkContext<Context> {

    // the standard reference counting header
    var ref: RefCounted

    // the thick function value for the thunk to call
    var function: ThickFunction<Context>
}
```

The first thunk that we go through has 3 parameters:

1. A pointer to where the return value should be stored
2. A pointer to where the arguments for the function are located
3. The context object which contains the actual thick function value to call (such as shown above)

This first thunk just extracts the function value from the context, and then calls a *second* thunk, with 4 parameters:

1. A pointer to where the return value should be stored
2. A pointer to where the arguments for the function are located
3. The raw function pointer to call
4. The pointer to the context of the function to call

This thunk now retrieves the arguments (if any) from the argument pointer, then calls the given function pointer with these arguments, along with its context. It then stores the return value (if any) at the address of the return pointer.

Like in the previous examples, we can test this like so:

```
func makeClosure() -> () -> Void {
    var i = 5
    return { i += 2 }
}

func printSingleCapturedValue<T>(t: T) {

    let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    ptr.initialize(to: t)

    let ctx = ptr.withMemoryRebound(to:
        ThickFunction<ReabstractionThunkContext<Box<Int>>>.self, capacity: 1) {
        // get the context from the thunk function value, which we can
        // then get the actual function value from, and therefore the actual
        // context object.
        $0.pointee.context!.pointee.function.context!
    }

    // print out captured value in the context object
    print(ctx.pointee.value)

    ptr.deinitialize()
    ptr.deallocate(capacity: 1)
}

let closure = makeClosure()

printSingleCapturedValue(t: closure) // 5
closure()
printSingleCapturedValue(t: closure) // 7
```

---

### Escaping vs. non-escaping capture

When the compiler can determine that the capture of a given local variable doesn't escape the lifetime of the function it's declared in, [it can optimise by promoting](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#guaranteed-optimization-and-diagnostic-passes) the value of that variable from the heap-allocated box to the stack (this is a guaranteed optimisation, and occurs in even -Onone). Then, the function's context object need only store a *pointer* to the given captured value on the stack, as it is guaranteed not to be needed after the function exits.

This can therefore be done when the closure(s) capturing the variable are known not to escape the lifetime of the function.

Generally, an escaping closure is one that either:

- Is stored in a non-local variable (including being returned from the function).
- Is captured by another escaping closure.
- Is passed as an argument to a function where that parameter is either marked as `@escaping`, or is not of function type (note this includes composite types, such as *optional* function types).

So, the following are examples where the capture of a given variable can be considered not to escape the lifetime of the function:

```
// the parameter is non-escaping, as is of function type and is not marked @escaping.
func nonEscaping(_ f: () -> Void) {
    f()
}

func bar() -> String {

    var str = ""

    // c doesn't escape the lifetime of bar().
    let c = {
        str += "c called; "
    }

    c();

    // immediately-evaluated closure obviously doesn't escape.
    { str += "immediately-evaluated closure called; " }()

    // closure passed to non-escaping function parameter, so doesn't escape.
    nonEscaping {
        str += "closure passed to non-escaping parameter called."
    }

    return str
}
```

In this example, because `str` is only ever captured by closures that are known not to escape the lifetime of the function `bar()`, the compiler can optimise by storing the value of `str` on the stack, with the context objects storing only a pointer to it ([the relevant IR](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/f3e0baf3dd4d20d614629b34936b1977#non-escaping-capture-stack-promotion)).

So, the context objects for each of the closures<sup>1</sup> will look like `Box<UnsafePointer<String>>`, with pointers to the string value on the stack. Although unfortunately, in a Schrödinger-like manner, attempting to observe this by allocating and re-binding a pointer (like before) triggers the compiler to treat the given closure as escaping – so we're once again looking at a `Box<String>` for the context.

In order to deal with the disparity between context objects that hold pointer(s) to the captured values rather than holding the values in their own heap-allocated boxes – Swift creates specialised implementations of the closures that take pointers to the captured values as arguments.

Then, a thunk is created for each closure that simply takes in a given context object, extracts the pointer(s) to the captured values from it, and passes this onto the specialised implementation of the closure. Now, we can just have a pointer to this thunk along with our context object as the thick function value.

For multiple captured values that don't escape, the additional pointers are simply added onto the end of the box, i.e

```
struct TwoNonEscapingCaptureContext<T, U> {

    // reference counting header
    var ref: RefCounted

    // pointers to captured values (on the stack)...
    var first: UnsafePointer<T>
    var second: UnsafePointer<U>
}
```

This optimisation of promoting the captured values from the heap to the stack can be *especially* beneficial in this case, as we're no longer having to allocate separate boxes for each value – such as was the case previously.

Furthermore it's worth noting that lots of cases with non-escaping closure capture can be optimised much more aggressively in -O builds with inlining, which can result in context objects being optimised away entirely.

---

<sup>1. Immediately-evaluated closures actually don't use a context object, the pointer(s) to the captured values are just passed directly to it upon calling.</sup>

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! Thank you! Could you share insight on how to invoke the function through the pointer?

Comment: @IanBytchek Glad to have been of help! I am planning on updating the answer for Swift 5 at some point now that we've hit ABI stability. If the function pointer doesn't involve captures (is thin), then you should just be able to `unsafeBitcast` to the equivalent function type (+ `@convention(thin)`). If however the function pointer does involve captures, I don't believe there's an easy way to call it.

Comment: Yes, it does! But falls short without a hard-coded struct, I can see a comment why… is there a way to do this magic directly on top-level functions or class methods? Any further information on this matter would be AMAZING!