# How do closures in Swift capture variables under the hood?

Tags: swift, closures

I am trying out to figure out how does capturing in Swift closures work.

Let's assume the following code example

```
class Worker {
    let block: () -> Void
    let id: String

    init(id: String, block: @escaping  () -> Void) {
        self.id = id
        self.block = block
    }
}

var worker: Worker!

worker = Worker(id: "1", block: { _ in
    print(worker.id)
})
```

At the moment the closure is being created, the worker variable is still nil. However, the closure will successfully capture the worker variable.

How does that work? How does the closure keep a strong reference to a variable that still not being initialized?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/43171341/2976878

Comment: Note that `worker` *is* initialised in your example, it is implicitly initialised to `nil` (and then you *assign* it a reference to a new `Worker` instance).

Comment: The worker is in fact initialized, but at a later point. At the moment the closure is created, the worker is still nil.

Comment: My point is that being `nil` *is* initialised. `nil` and uninitialised are two completely different states. For one, you cannot capture a variable before it has been initialised (try `var i: Int; let c = { i += 1 }`).

Comment: You are correct, the variable gets initialized with nil.

Answer (score 0):

Closures in Swift capture all variables *by reference*, just like how variables declared as `__block` are captured by blocks in Objective-C. Therefore, changes to the variable outside the closure after the closure is created are still seen in the closure when it runs.